# Durrett's definition of $\sigma$-algebra missing one condition?

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

I'm just starting to read Durrett's Probability: Theory and Examples (5th ed.). Durrett defines a $\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal{F}$ as a nonempty collection of subsets of a set $\Omega$ satisfying

(i) if $A \in \mathcal{F}$ then $A^c \in \mathcal{F}$

(ii) if $A_i \in \mathcal{F}$ is a countable sequence of sets then $\cup_i A_i \in \mathcal{F}$.

Typically, I have seen the definition of a $\sigma$-algebra with a third condition, (iii) $\Omega \in \mathcal{F}$. Of course, this implies $\emptyset \in \mathcal{F}$ due to (i).

I can't piece together $\Omega, \emptyset \in \mathcal{F}$ from (i) and (ii) alone and I don't think we can really proceed without $\Omega, \emptyset \in \mathcal{F}$, so what gives?

Comment: It's "non-empty" (this is your second sentence). Hence there is at least one $A\in \mathcal F$ which implies $A^c \in \mathcal F$, implying $A \cup A^c = \Omega \in \mathcal F$.

Comment: @AndrewZhang Yup, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two possible definitions. Bourbaki sides with Durrett by not asking $\emptyset$ to be a member of the $\sigma$-algebra. Most textbooks nowadays ask for this additional condition.

Note that it boils down to the following question: should we allow a $\sigma$-algebra to be empty?
I have no opinion on the question and it seems that it has no consequence at all on the theory.

Indeed if a $\sigma$-algebra is not empty, it contains some set $A$, its complement $A^c$ and the intersection of these two, $\emptyset = A \cap A^c$.

Comment: So Durrett requires a $\sigma$-algebra to be nonempty.  Is there an author whose definition allows a $\sigma$-algebra to be empty?

Comment: @BrianMoehring Bourbaki.

Comment: In which of their books?

Comment: Integration. Probably the first one. And indeed as the OP, I didn't see that Durrett asked the $\sigma$-algebra to be non-empty.

Comment: To be fair, Durrett puts nonempty in parentheses. I suppose without this condition we'd require for either $\Omega$ or $\emptyset$ to be in $\mathcal{F}$. Thanks!